# Logic to identify the "minimal paths" in a directed (ordered) acyclic graph (DAG)

Tags: logic, graph-theory

I am a reliability engineer and nowadays trying to write a code which analyse complex reliability block diagrams (RBD). (my profession is industrial eng.)

RBD properties (valid always):

1. directed (ordered) acyclic graph - DAG
2. Has only 1 source vertex (generic or real; type doesn't matter)
3. Has only 1 sink vertex (generic or real; type doesn't matter)

For the image below please notice that there are 5 paths that are:

1. acef
2. acdf
3. abef
4. abdf
5. adf

[image]

BUT there are only 3 minimal paths that are:

1. acef
2. abef
3. adf

Those below are not minimal

1. acdf
2. abdf

**question 1:** I am not a mathematician and you maybe saw RBD term for the first time in your life however minimal path term is I think a graph theory term so I ask in this question: Is my understanding of minimal term correct?

acdf and abdf are not minimal paths since vertex a can directly reach to vertex d so longer paths (including more than 2 vertexes) are not minimal. path ad is 1 step. Path acd and abd have 2 steps from a to d.  So each path a****d can not be minimal. (**** means some vertexes between a & d) Is my understanding correct? (I've read definitions from papers but I didn't understand those strange mathematical tellings so please forgive my plain English requirement.)

**Question 2** Assuming my understanding is correct; I ask that is logic below correct which aims to select minimal paths in a DAG.

A little summary of the graph

```
                branch
vertex          level   note
------          -----   ----
a               0       source
(b,c,d)         1       adjacents of source
(d,e);(d,e);f   2       adjacents of b,c,d respectively
f,f,NULL        3       adjacents of d,e,f respectively
```

*my logic* : **paths that are connecting the vertexes in same level are not minimal except for sink vertex**.

So for example, there are 3 vertexes in level 1 branch: b and c and d. So any paths between these 3 vertexes won't be minimal.

```
---------------------------------
level   0   |   1   |   2   |   3
---------------------------------
        a   |   b   |   d   |   f
            |   c   |   e   |
            |   d   |   f   |
```

Remembering the top image; a**cd**f & a**bd**f are not minimal since they include at least a path from same level (level 1)

**df** (notice that d & f are in level 2, same level) is not affecting minimality since f is the sink vertex and excluded from my logic.

**Is my logic correct** (again in very plain English, sorry)

thanks for reading at least, it's been a long post.

Best regards

## UPDATE

(scope of update: extra information for the possible definition of "**minimal path**")

url: http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2014/07/complex-system-reliability/ is directly related to my case. Author doesn't give any explicit definition for "minimal path" term however "**mathematica software code**" may say something I hope. Also please shoot a glance just below the title in the url above: **"Minimal Paths, Inclusion-Exclusion, and System Reliability"**

I searched "module minimalpaths mathematica" in google but no useful result was found also I mailed to the author 2 weeks ago and I got no reply.

[image]

Comment: Minimal path might mean different things depending on the context. Could you provide some more info (e.g. do you have any _definition_ of minimal paths in your context, or perhaps a paper where you have seen the term)?

Comment: @dtldarek Hi, thanks for your interest. Only paper I could find for this topic was (url) http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2014/07/complex-system-reliability/ I also edited my question, added related part from the paper. As you can see,  author didn't gave an explicit def. of "minimal path" however I hope maybe mathematica formulation can say you some meaningful things. Best regards.

Comment: I found there this sentence: "Since we have chosen to use a directed acyclic graph to represent a system’s RBD, all paths are minimal. That is to say, all components in a path are distinct." But something is wrong, it seems that they are using paths minimal with regard to inclusion.

Comment: If I understand what are you trying to do, then your logic does not seem to be correct, imagine there are three more nodes $x,y,z$ on edges $ad$, $ab$ and $ac$ respectively. Then $aybdf$ connects vertices of the same level ($b$ and $d$), but it is a minimal path (you cannot remove $b$ as before, because there is no edge $y \to d$).